# Autocomplete files across multiple directories

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I tried to write a bash-script for execute a command with a prefix (`"DRI_PRIME=1 glxspheres"` for example). This is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

_graphic() {
    export IFS=":"
    PATHCONTENT=()
    for CONTENTPATH in $PATH; do
            PATHCONTENT+=$(ls $CONTENTPATH)
    done
    COMPREPLY=$PATHCONTENT;
}

complete -F _graphic graphic

DRI_PRIME=1 "$@"
```

But this script doesnt autocomplete the folders in the $PATH-variable. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is, but it seems that you want to have a way of telling

```
$ graphic my_app param blah
```

and it will actually run

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 my_app param blah
```

If that is so, it's rather easy, bash itself does that for you:

```
$ cat a.sh
function graphic {
        DRI_PRIME=1 "$@"
}

complete -A command graphic
```

**complete -A command** makes bash to suggest command names (you used **complete -F _graphic** which makes bash call function to obtain possible completions).